# Disable Menustrip based on table

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I want to enable/disable menus/sub menus based on a table.
My table structure has:

```
Group(group where the user belong)
Menu(Menu to enabled for this specific group).
```

I also have a `SqlDataReader` which return all the menus as a string.

e.g `Group=1 and Menu="MnuFile"`

How can I pass this string (`MnuFile`) to enable me doing `me.["MnuFile"].enable=true`? where `["MnuFile"]` is a string retrieved from a datareader? I'm using `vb.net2005` (winform) and sqlserver 2005.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
me.Controls["MnuFile"].enable=true
```

EDIT : above for main menu strip

```
mnuMainMenu.Items["MnuFile"].enable=true
```

for menu item

Comment: Thank u Jack Gajanan for your quick response. However,I'm getting NullReferenceException. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: only for mnustrip not for menu item also replace me with Container

Comment: thank you Jack Gajanan for the clarification. How to apply it for menu items?

Comment: mnuMainMenuStrip.Items["MnuFile"].enable=true